# What do you call something that causes fear?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> The wind and the owls weren't the/my only [...] that night.

I didn't using *fear* as a noun is a bit weird in this situation? What's a better alternative?

Comment: You could use [**frightener**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/frightener) though I don't think it's particularly common

Comment: [bugbear, bete noire, etc.](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/bugbear)

Comment: Worry, concern [mild]; terror [strong].

Comment: A *phobia*, or a source of *apprehension*.

Comment: As others are saying, **fear** is the best fit for that sentence.

Comment: a politician...

Comment: I don't think fear is the word you are going for, and neither did you.  I think eeriness probably fits better.  +1 for paying attention to your intuitions as a listener.

Comment: A scarecrow?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Using fear as a noun like this is perfectly acceptable. Most of the alternatives being suggested feel awkward in comparison. "My worst fear" and "my only fear" are common sentence fragments; google searches for them return 367k and 305k results respectively. Most tellingly) "the fear of" returns a whopping 47 million results.

You've already got the correct word - use it!

Answer (score 11):

[Fright](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Fright) may fit your context:

> - Sudden intense fear, as of something immediately threatening

Comment: You mean, frightening?

Comment: Isn't OP looking for a noun?

Comment: `I didn't using fear as a noun is a bit weird in this situation? What's a better alternative?` --> He is clearly asking a better alternative.

Comment: In that case you should suggest a rewording of the sentence!

Comment: Fright is the right word for the OP's demo sentence.

Comment: `The wind and the owls weren't the only frightening things that night.` --> Isn't this correct?

Comment: Also notice that the sentence, with fright, should be `[...] weren't my only fright [...]`.

Comment: You should make your suggestions to OP, not to me!!

Comment: I'm completeing your answer. It won't work if the O.P. uses `the`. If you notice, he has `the/my` in the question, leaving a choice for the answered to choose.

Answer (score 11):

One option is [Terror](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/terror?s=t)

> 5. *Informal.* a person or thing that is especially annoying or unpleasant.

Even more so in British usage:

> 2. A person or thing that inspires great dread

This fits pretty well into your sentence:

> The wind and the owls weren't the only terror that night.

Answer (score 7):

How about :

> The wind and the owls weren't the only **fearsome** things that night.

Comment: I feel fearsome in this sense implies the wind and the owls are themselves fearsome, rather than conveying the OP's fear of them

Comment: @Robotnik Yes, it's not a perfect fit and also difficult for me to voice because I'm not at all frightened by wind or owls :-)

Comment: This was also the first thing that came to mind for me, but I agree, not a perfect fit.  I think the accepted answer "fear" is quite likely the best.

Answer (score 6):

There are two words I can come up with:

- *scary* — something that makes you scared, with fear
- *frightening* — something that causes you fear

---

As I brought up in a comment to another answer, you may reword your sentence to:

> The wind and the owls weren't the only frightening/scary things that night.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Bogeyman/men](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bogeyman?s=t). Whilst this has the literal meaning ascribed in the link, I believe it can also be used to refer to a more general fear, perhaps commonly "of the night".

> The wind and the owls weren't the only bogeymen that night.

Answer (score 2):

Something that causes fear is *frightening*.

It works in your context, too:

> The wind and the owls were not the only frightening things [that]/[in the] night.

Answer (score 1):

A more formal word for fear (as a noun) is a *phobia*

> The wind and the owls weren't my only phobias that night.

Something a little less extreme might be *worry* or *concern*

> The wind and the owls weren't my only worries that night.
>
> The wind and the owls weren't my only concerns that night.

Honestly, I don't thing using the word fear here would be that odd at all. Of course, that depends on whether or not you have just recently used in (i.e., in the previous sentence).

Comment: I would say "phobia" is generally used to denote an anxiety disorder or a strong irrational fear.  In fact I can't think of ever hearing used outside that context.

Answer (score 0):

Consider *[tormenter](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tormenter)* (or *tormentor*)

> a person or thing that torments

*Collins*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online* defines *[torment](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/torment)* as

> Severe physical or mental suffering

Answer (score 0):

a great word for something that causes fear is a "menace."

it works here, too, depending on the tone of what you're writing:

> The wind and the owls were not the only menaces in that night.

Comment: Owls are not usually considered to be a menace. Fear speaks more to perception, whereas menace speaks to potential for causing actual harm.

Answer (score 0):

The wind and the owls weren't the/my only unease that night.

The wind and the owls were not the only apprehensions that night.

The wind and owls were not all I dread that night.

Answer (score -1):

A few words that might ring a bell-

If the fear gave an almost pleasurable sensation of fright/a sudden numbing, you can use:

- [chill](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=chill%20meaning&hl=en-IN&gbv=2&oq=&gs_l=), shudder, etc.

To indicate a fearful expectation or anticipation:

- [premonition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/premonition)

If the fear resulted from the awareness of danger, you may use:

- [consternation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consternation)

Reference- TFD

Answer (score -1):

- The wind and the owls weren't the only formidable beasts that night.
- The wind and the owls weren't my only frightful opponents that night.
- The wind and the owls weren't my only dreadful adversaries I had that night.
- The wind and the owls weren't the only adversaries I dreaded that night.